# Triggering A modal from within a countdown function

Tags: angular7, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap modal to be triggered when my jsonwebtoken is close to expiring.

I am able to get the modal to fire via a button on the nav bar, but I cannot get the modal to trigger from the function.

when i try to trigger the modal using this.openRenew(renew); i get an cannot find name renew error,

```
**** navbar.html
<!-- Renew Token -->
<ng-template #renew let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="renewModal">Renew Log In</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close 
            (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Your Session In About To Expire.
        For Security Please Confirm Your Password To Continue.
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Password" name="password">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" 
            (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Log Back In</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>


**** navbar.ts

constructor(
    public _auth:AuthService,
    public _router:Router,
    public modalService: NgbModal) {
        this._auth.time.subscribe((now: Date) => {
            this.currentTime = now.valueOf();
            if(!!this._auth.emToken){
                if (!this.timeToRenew || this._auth.emExpTime==null){
                    console.log('Checking Time to renew', 
                        this._auth.emExpTime*1000-this.currentTime );
                    if((this._auth.emExpTime*1000)-45000<this.currentTime){
                        this.timeToRenew = true;
                        console.log('Time to Log Back In');
                         / * Need to trigger openRenew() here *
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

openRenew(renew) {
    this.modalService.open(renew, {ariaLabelledBy: 
         'renewModal'}).result.then(
         (result) => {
             console.log(result);
             // validate password 
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rchtnc?file=app/modal-basic.ts) to show this working. It should automatically display the modal after around 10 seconds.

There's a couple of changes you'll need to make to your code to get this to work:

i. Make sure you can get a reference to the modal template in your TS file by using the following code to declare the template as a class variable and using `@ViewChild` to get a reference to it in the HTML:

```
@ViewChild('renew')
private renew: TemplateRef<any>;
```

I've modified the logic to make it simpler for the demo - in this example the `AuthService` fires the time every 5 seconds. The component listens to this and if the timestamp emitted by the `AuthService` is greater than 10 seconds after the component was created, it displays the modal.

ii. You will need assign the subscription to a variable `subscription` so that you can then unsubscribe when you open the modal:

```
// 1. Maintain a reference to the subscription
const subscription: Subscription = this._auth.time.subscribe((now: Date) => {
    ...
    if (/*should renew*/) {
        this.openRenew(this.renew);
        subscription.unsubscribe(); // 2. Unsubscribe here after opening modal
    }
});
```

This prevents additional modals being displayed on top of the original one every time the `AuthService` emits a timestamp.